# Dynamically set Image is lost on rotate

Tags: java, android, eclipse, user-interface, android-fragments

Please have a look at the following code

**OutputFragment.java**

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class OutputFragment extends Fragment implements AsyncResponse{

    private ImageView backButton, resultOfferImage;
    private EditText offerEdt, confidenceEdt, typeEdt;
    JsonController j;
    private View view;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private DataSaver dataSaver;
    private Bundle savedInstance;
    private static int resultOfferImageInt = 0;


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //Intializing instance variables
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.output, container,false);


        backButton = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.back_button);
        resultOfferImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.result_image);



        offerEdt = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.offer_edt);
        confidenceEdt = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.confidence_edt);
        typeEdt = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.type_of_user_edt);

        dataSaver = DataSaver.getInstance();

        if(savedInstanceState==null){
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...Generating Results...");
        progressDialog.show();
        }
        //Registering the Listeners
        backButton.setOnClickListener(new BackButtonAction());

        j = JsonController.getInstance();
        j.delegate = OutputFragment.this;

        return view;

    }


    //ActionListener for the manual back button
    private class BackButtonAction implements OnClickListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager(); 
            fm.popBackStackImmediate();

        }

    }


    @Override
    public void processFinish(String output) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("OUTPUT_FRAGMENT", output);

        try {
            JSONObject finalResult = new JSONObject(output);

            //Set the Confidence
            JSONObject jb1 = finalResult.getJSONObject("prediction_path");
            Double confidence = jb1.getDouble("confidence");
            confidence = confidence*100;
            confidenceEdt.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(confidence*100)/100)+"%");

            //Set the type of User
            String user = finalResult.getString("output");
            typeEdt.setText(user);

            Log.d("DataSaver_getConfidence", ""+dataSaver.getConfidence());

            if((dataSaver.getConfidence())>confidence)
            {
                offerEdt.setText("No");
                resultOfferImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_message_required);
                resultOfferImageInt = R.drawable.no_message_required;
            }
            else
            {
                if(user.toLowerCase().equals("whale"))
                {
                    offerEdt.setText("Yes");
                    resultOfferImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.eventinier_whale);
                    resultOfferImageInt = R.drawable.eventinier_whale;
                }
                else if(user.toLowerCase().equals("fish"))
                {
                    offerEdt.setText("Yes");
                    resultOfferImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.tiny_fish);
                    resultOfferImageInt = R.drawable.tiny_fish;
                }
                else if(user.toLowerCase().equals("minnow"))
                {
                    offerEdt.setText("Yes");
                    resultOfferImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.tiny_minnow);
                    resultOfferImageInt = R.drawable.tiny_minnow;
                }
                else
                {
                    resultOfferImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_message_required);
                    offerEdt.setText("Yes");
                    resultOfferImageInt = R.drawable.no_message_required;
                }
            }

            Log.d("OUTPUT_CONFIDENCE", confidence+"");


            progressDialog.dismiss();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

This fragment get called by **InputFragment.java** and as you can see, all the fields are filled by the method `processFinish()` which is a call back function. This function get called as a result of network operation done in `InputFragment.java`. However the issue is, when this fragment is called by `InputFragment.java` it displays all the fields, with the images. Now, if I rotate the device, all the fields are getting displayed expect the `resultOfferImage`. There is no image there! It is gone! When all other dynamically allocated values are getting displayed, why this image is getting lost?

Please note that I must put the code `if(savedInstanceState==null)` in `onCreateView()` otherwise this starts displaying the `ProgressDialog` on rotation and do nothing. What is wrong here? Why this image is getting lost on rotate?

Answer (score 0):

try setting

```
    setRetainInstance(true);
```

in onCreateView() method of **InputFragment.java**